# How to convert a int to float in LLVM C?

Tags: c, llvm

What exactly writing equivalent C

```
int a=10;
float b=0;

b = (float)(a+1.0);
```

in llvm-c I can create value but how convert it to other type?
How writing this is C-LLVM.

```
LLVMValueRef b = LLVMBuildAdd(builder,
  LLVMGetParam(function, 0),
  LLVMGetParam(function, 1), "b");
```

Comment: this is not C version, but yes very similar. You know how convert i32 to float in C? exactly one line in C == CastInst* float_conv = new SIToFPInst(int32_a, Type::getFloatTy(mod->getContext()), "conv", label_entry);  llvm-c is a little different llvm-c++

Comment: AIUI you're not really meant to write code using that API; it exists primarily to suit the convenience of wrappers for other languages, because wrapping C++ directly can be a bit of a pain. The general answer to your question is to look for how to do it using C++ and then look in the LLVM-C source for a wrapper function that does what you found, and finally call the LLVM-C wrapper you found. Good luck.

Comment: @arnt I need using C because my parser using C